# Reading multiple arrays containing multiple dictionaries containing multiple arryes from a plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, sigabrt

Hi guys I want to read the following plist file into memory and do some calculations with the results, the plist file looks as follows this is only part of it to show the structure:

```
<dict>
<key>Stations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>Hatfield</string>
        <key>Coords</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Lat</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Long</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>Routes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>H1 Hatfield - Brooklyn</string>
                <key>Stops</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Name</key>
                        <string>Burnett St &amp; Festival St</string>
                        <key>Coords</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Lat</key>
                            <string>-25.75081</string>
                            <key>Long</key>
                            <string>28.23272</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Name</key>
                        <string>University Rd &amp; Lynwood Rd</string>
                        <key>Coords</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Lat</key>
                            <string>-25.75592</string>
                            <key>Long</key>
                            <string>28.22517</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Name</key>
                        <string>Roper St &amp; Charles St</string>
                        <key>Coords</key>
                        <dict>
                            <key>Lat</key>
                            <string>-25.76463</string>
                            <key>Long</key>
                            <string>28.22737</string>
                        </dict>
                    </dict>
```

Currently I am trying to read them using the following:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Busses.plist"];

NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];

NSMutableArray *arrayOfStationsFromFile = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[plistData objectForKey:@"Stations"], nil] retain];


for(int i = 0; i < [arrayOfStationsFromFile count]; i++)
{

    NSDictionary *stationWithBusses = (NSDictionary *)[[arrayOfStationsFromFile objectAtIndex:i] retain];
    NSMutableArray *routes = [[stationWithBusses objectForKey:@"Routes"] retain];
    for(int j = 0; j < [routes count]; j++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *routesData = [routes objectAtIndex:j];
        NSString *name = [routesData objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSMutableArray *stops = [routesData objectForKey:@"Stops"];
        for(int x = 0; x < [stops count]; x++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *stopsData = [stops objectAtIndex:x];
            NSString *subName = [stopsData objectForKey:@"Name"];
            NSMutableDictionary *coords = [stopsData objectForKey:@"Coords"];
            NSString *latt = [coords objectForKey:@"Lat"];
            NSString *longs = [coords objectForKey:@"Long"];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
            coordinate.latitude = [latt longLongValue];
            coordinate.longitude = [longs longLongValue];
            [busses addObject:[[Busses alloc] initWithName:name subName:subName coordinate:coordinate]];
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a SIGABRT at this line

```
NSMutableArray *routes = [[stationWithBusses objectForKey:@"Routes"] retain];
```

First line of console output:

```
2011-08-30 12:31:57.699 GautrainiPhone[12633:e903] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5ba6c10
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: PLEASE GIVE US NSLOG FORMAT OF PLIST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the message+location implies `stationWithBusses` is an `NSArray` (not `NSDictionary`)

Comment: `stationWithBusses` is an NSArray. i can't simplify that. if you tell me what you don't understand about it, i could help.

Comment: But stationWithBusses is an NSDictionary.

`NSDictionary *stationWithBusses = [[arrayOfStationsFromFile objectAtIndex:i] retain];`

Comment: you have *declared* `stationWithBusses` a NSDictionary. the actual type returned (for at minimum one element) is an `NSArray`. there is no runtime conversion to the variable you have declared -- the language gives you the responsibility of properly declaring types returned from collections. this is the same problem you have with string representations of numbers. i know the type type is NSArray because of the console message (`__NSCFArray`). the types are all declared in the xml.

Comment: I see what you mean now, so how can I fix such a problem?

Comment: I made a few changes in plist and now it works, with some help from the suggestions made from @AppleVijay

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace first lines with my code:

```
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:finalPath];
NSMutableDictionary *plistData = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfStationsFromFile = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[plistData valueForKey:@"Stations"]];
```